# How do I access a variable from one class which takes it from another?

Tags: swift, oop

I am trying to get my ingredients name (FoodName) which is in the class SpecificFood. The meal class has a property mealIngredients which contains ingredients objects.

Now in the table view I am trying to refer to the foodName in the mealingredients such, however, it doesn't find the foodName because that is referring to the SpecificFood rather than the meal class. I input the names for everything and the ingredients into different foods in a separate model class.

If there is better way of doing this then please do let me know as I'm new to swift and programming.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
let meal = self.selectedMeal

        let ingredientTitle = meal?.mealIngredients[indexPath.row].FoodName

        cell.textLabel?.text = String(ingredientTitle)

        return cell
```

I have made reference to all the different classes in the top such;

```
 var myMeals:Array = [Meal]()
    var meals:[Meal] = [Meal]()
    var ingredients:[SpecificFood] = [SpecificFood]()
```

My meal class is such;

```
class Meal: NSObject {



    var mealTitle:String = ""
    var mealID:String = ""
    // var mealIngredients:NSArray = [NSObject]()
    var mealIngredients:NSArray = [SpecificFood]()

}
```

My SpecificFood class is such;

```
class SpecificFood: NSObject {

    var foodName = ""
    var foodGroup = ""

}
```

Then my model is like such; (I've taken some of the other foods and ingredients but this gives the jist.

```
class MealModel: NSObject {

    var ingredients:[SpecificFood] = [SpecificFood]()



    func getMeals() -> [Meal] {

 var allFoods = [SpecificFood]()
 let meat = String()

 let chicken = SpecificFood()
 let rice = SpecificFood()

// Assign properties of the SpecificFoods
 chicken.foodName = "Chicken"
 chicken.foodGroup = meat

// Add foods to my food array
 allFoods.append(chicken)

// Create a meal objects
var meal1 = Meal()


// Assign properties
 meal1.mealIngredients = [chicken, rice, tomatoeSauce]
```

The top two pieces of code refer to the class with the tableView in. It has no other code in apart from `var selectedMeal:Meal?`

Comment: Can you show your class variables

Comment: @Shades does this help? I have tried to show all the information that I can. I think it is the object oriented programming and inheritance where I am becoming confused.

Comment: In your code, is FoodName capitalized in this line: let ingredientTitle = meal?.mealIngredients[indexPath.row].FoodName

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your class variables it is a bit hard...  I'll post this generic example:

```
class firstViewController: UIViewController {
    var someVariable: SomeType = someValue
    var someVariable2: SomeType = someValue

    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }
}
```

Then instantiate the view:

```
var myCustomViewController: firstViewController = firstViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
var variable = myCustomViewController.someVariable
var variable2 = myCustomViewController.someVariable2
```

Comment: Does this help any more? Sorry for the unclear first question.

Comment: Try Instantiating your class and getting the variables as I showed in this example. Remember the variables from the 'source' class have to be to be public and global, ore create methods to access them if they are private

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
meal1.mealIngredients = [chicken, rice, tomatoeSauce]
```

then you access chicken's name and food group with:

```
meal1.mealIngredients[0].foodName   // Chicken
meal1.mealIngredients[0].foodGroup   // meat
```

---

You may want to consider using structs instead of classes (unless you're already using inheritance).

```
struct SpecificFood {
    var foodName = ""
    var foodGroup = ""
}

struct Meal {
    var mealTitle:String = ""
    var mealID:String = ""
    var mealIngredients: [SpecificFood]
}
```

Your code becomes:

```
let chicken = SpecificFood(foodName: "Chicken", foodGroup: "meat")
var meal1 = Meal(mealTitle: "Chicken and Rice", mealID: "45634", mealIngredients: [])
```

and you access the properties with the dot (.) syntax.